# UISplitViewController is not rotating correctly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I know there is a lot of discussion on this topic on stack overflow, but none of the questions have an answer that works for me.

I have a SplitViewController that loads as the root view controller, and both of the tableviews inside the SVC have ShouldAutoRotate set to return YES.

The SVC won't rotate with the iPad correctly, even though the clock / status bar do.

---

**Update**

In my AppDelegate, I've noticed that the rootViewController isn't actually set until after I set it - shouldn't the rootViewController always be set?
This code:

```
    MyAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"RootViewController pre set: %@", appDelegate.window.rootViewController);
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
    NSLog(@"RootViewController post set: %@", appDelegate.window.rootViewController);
```

Logs as:

```
RootViewController pre set: (null)
RootViewController post set: <UISplitViewController: 0x88ad2d0>
```

Does this mean that I am mistaken in thinking the SVC is the root view controller?

Also, in IB - the window has nothing hooked up to the rootViewController outlet - is this a problem?

---

Here's where the SVC is programmatically made:

```
-(IBAction)makeStory:(id)sender{
 MakeSentenceTableViewController *detailViewController = [[MakeSentenceTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeSentenceTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *rootNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:makeStoryTableViewController]autorelease];

    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, detailNav, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate        = makeStoryTableViewController;

    MyAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
}
```

Here is the ShouldAutoRotate section in both tableviews (they're identical in both):

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {  
    NSLog(@"story idiom for rotate is iPad");
    return YES;
}
```

Please help me fix this so that the SplitViewController loads correctly - or help me out with some techniques to debug (e.g. how could I check for sure that the SVC is in the rootViewController, are there other methods to debugging rotation hassles?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. So often part of the process in asking a question leads you to answer it to yourself.

I had to hook up the rootViewController outlet in IB for MainWindow~ipad.xib to the viewController in the AppDelegate, then everything started working.

So I hadn't correctly set the UISplitViewController as the rootViewController.