# Accessing a UITableView when a UINavigationController gets in the way (in a UISplitViewController)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController that is set up like so:

```
-(IBAction)makeStory:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"makeStory:");

    makeStoryTableViewController = [[MakeStoryTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeStoryTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    MakeSentenceTableViewController *detailViewController = [[MakeSentenceTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeSentenceTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *rootNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:makeStoryTableViewController]autorelease];

    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, detailNav, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate        = makeStoryTableViewController;

    StoryBotAppDelegate *appDelegate = (StoryBotAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
}
```

When I try to set detailView in the UISplitView delegate as a result of didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, I can only access the NavigationController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    NSLog(@"ViewControllers: %@", [self.splitViewController viewControllers]);
    MakeSentenceTableViewController *detailViewController = [[self.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    Story *storySet = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"detailViewController: %@", detailViewController); //Logs a UINavigationController
    [detailViewController setStory:storySet]; //Fails here because Navigation Controllers Can't setStory!
    [detailViewController refreshTables];
}
```

Which makes sense, but how do I access the TableViews that the UINavigationControllers are responsible for? If I remove *rootNav and *detailNav and replace them with the UITableViews in the splitViewController.viewControllers statement it works fine, but then I have no navigation bar:

```
    MakeSentenceTableViewController *detailViewController = [[MakeSentenceTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeSentenceTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    //UINavigationController *rootNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:makeStoryTableViewController]autorelease];

    //UINavigationController *detailNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:makeStoryTableViewController, detailViewController, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate        = makeStoryTableViewController;

    StoryBotAppDelegate *appDelegate = (StoryBotAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
```

**How can I access the Detail TableView Controller and keep the Navigation Bar?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I figured it out. I made two mistakes, and in those mistakes I had to use the *UINavigationController.viewControllers ObjectAtIndex:* property.

1. In the function makeStory I was incorrectly assigning a UINavigationController as a delegate instead of a makeStoryTableViewController. I fixed it by doing this, instead (pay special attention to the splitViewController.delegate section):

   ```
   MakeSentenceTableViewController *detailViewController = [[MakeSentenceTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeSentenceTableViewController" bundle:nil]; 
   UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

   UINavigationController *rootNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:makeStoryTableViewController]autorelease];

   UINavigationController *detailNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

   splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, detailNav, nil];

   //splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:makeStoryTableViewController, detailViewController, nil];
   //RootViewController *root = (RootViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]

   splitViewController.delegate        = [rootNav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

   NSLog(@"delegate: %@",  [rootNav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]);

   StoryBotAppDelegate *appDelegate = (StoryBotAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSLog(@"RootViewController: %@", appDelegate.window);

   [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];

   NSLog(@"AppDelegate.window: %@", appDelegate.window.rootViewController);
   ```
2. I made the same mistake again, this time in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and tried to setStory in a UINavigationController. To fix it, I did this (pay special attention to the bit about navControllerDetail.viewControllers:

   ```
   UINavigationController *navControllerDetail;
   navControllerDetail = [[self.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];



   MakeSentenceTableViewController *detailViewController;

   detailViewController = [navControllerDetail.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

   Story *storySet = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];



   NSLog(@"detailViewController: %@", detailViewController);
   [detailViewController setStory:storySet];
   [detailViewController refreshTables];
   ```

Now if only I could figure out how to get the [SplitViewController to rotate properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612036/uisplitviewcontroller-is-not-rotating-correctly)!